# Thrift framework for iPhone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, thrift

I'm currently stuck trying to get my objective c generated files to compile in my iPhone project. Basically it keeps telling me there is no such directory for the following four imports:

Thrift/TProtocol.h
Thrift/TApplicationException.h
Thrift/TProtocolUtil.h
Thrift/TProcessor.h

I'm following all the instructions on the Thrift wiki and have downloaded and compiled the Thrift framework in XCode but there is no information specific to iPhone development. I'm almost certain it's a problem specific to an iPhone project because if I create a new command line project in XCode, I can import those files just fine.

Comment: I found a folder called Thrift.framework and included it in my target's Linked Libraries. Now there's no problem finding the imports but linking them.

By default the Thrift.framework project compiles for x86_64. If building for the simulator it tells me it has to be i386 which I change the Thrift overview to. If I'm compiling for the device it tells me it has to be in arm which I can't compile the Thrift project in.

Either way (in 64, 386, for simulator, or for device) I get the following:

Comment: Undefined symbols:
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_TProtocolUtil", referenced from:
        objc-class-ref-to-TProtocolUtil in gen_1.o
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_TApplicationException", referenced from:
        objc-class-ref-to-TProtocolUtil in gen_1.o
ld: symbol(s) not found
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After retaining the services of some kind of sorcerer I have figured out how to get Thrift to work with the iPhone/iPad (or at least get it to compile okay).

First, you want to grab the objective-c files with this command instead of from the wiki:

```
svn co http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/incubator/thrift/trunk/lib/cocoa/src/ thrift-cocoa
```

Then, make a new Xcode project by going to New Project, selecting Framework & Library and Cocoa Framework. Click create and save it somewhere nice. Right click on Targets and select Add -> New Target. Choose Cocoa Touch and then Static Library. Give it a nice name. Go to the target's Build tab in info and change the Base SDK to iPhone Device (I'm using 3.2 but you can use whatever) and change Architectures to either Standard (armv6 armv7) or Optimized (armv7). Under the General tab add the Foundation and Cocoa frameworks.

Drag all of the files and folders you got from the svn repository into the Classes folder in the project. Check the copy items box and check the boxes next to both targets. Remove TSocketServer.h and .m from the Static Library's Copy Headers and Compile Sources folders respectively. You can now build the Static Library (and Framework optionally).

Open the project you want to use Thrift in and go to your target's General tab in info. Add the Static Library you just created to the Linked Libraries list. It should be named libYOUR_TARGET_NAME.a. Under the build tab go to Header Search Paths and add the path to the Thrift project you just created and check the recursive box.

Finally you just need to change the import statements in the Thrift generated code by simply removing the brackets and replacing them with quotes. You can now build you iPhone project again.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding those .h files to your Xcode project.

Comment: Just pull the header files from the Thrift.framework project for XCode and put them in my project?

I'll try it, but I don't understand why I'm building the framework in the first place then.